# Maximization of function with respect to constraint

Tags: real-analysis, optimization, lagrange-multiplier

Consider the problem for some vectors $v, m \in \mathbb{R}^n:$

$$f(v) = (v^T m)^2$$ w.r.t $\|v\|^2 =1$

I want to maximize $f$

If I consider the lagrangian, I get:

$$L(v)=(v^T m)^2 + \lambda(1 - \|v\|^2)$$

Taking derivative, I get: $2 mm^Tv - \lambda2 v =0 $
Therefore $mm^Tv = \lambda v (*)$

Multiplying by v^T from left, I end up with $$(v^Tm)^2 = \lambda $$

If I put that in(*), I do cannot simplfy that.

Is there a trick I can apply?

Comment: (*) is just $(m^Tv) m = \lambda v$ (note: $m^Tv$ is a scalar.)

Comment: Then I would get: $m= \lambda' v \Rightarrow v^T m = \lambda'$

Comment: Then $m - v^T m v =0$

Comment: Can I do something about it?

Comment: Then $v = \alpha m$ for some $\alpha$.

Comment: But how do I get the alpha?

Comment: From $\|v\| ^2= 1$, we get $\|\alpha m\|^2 = 1$ or $\alpha^2 \|m\|^2 = 1$.

Answer (score 1):

You do not need much optimization here. Just note that $(v^Tm)^2=v^Tmm^Tv$ and that $mm^T$ is symmetric positive semidefinite with rank 1. The only nonnezero eigenvalue is given by $m^Tm$. Therefore, we have that

$$0\le v^Tmm^Tv\le m^Tm$$ for all $v\in\mathbb{R}^n$. The maximum is attained for $v=m/||m||$ which is normalized eigenvector associated with the unique positive eigenvalue. Note that it is also attained for $v=-m/||m||$.

The difficulty here with using Lagrange multipliers is that $mm^T$ is not invertible and one has to restrict $v$ to the subspace where $mm^Tv\ne0$. That is you can solve for the problem where $v=\alpha m$ and pick $\alpha$ such that the norm of $v$ is one.